# convergence of improper integral $\int_0 ^1 x(1-\log x)^{2a} dx$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I need to check whether the integral converges or not.

The integral is

$\int_0 ^1 x(1-\log x)^{2a} dx$

I see the integrand is continuous on the domain $(0,1)$, so I think if the limit at the endpoints exists then we can conclude that the integral converges, right??

The limit at the upper bound is zero, but the problem is to calculate the limit at the lower bound $x=0^+$.
I tried to calculate the limit using L'Hopital's rule, and get zero for any value of $a$, but not sure if this is true.

Any idea or suggestion!

Comment: Yes, the integral exists for any $a$ and its value is $e^2 E_{-2 a}(2)$ where $$E_n (z)=\int _1^{\infty }\frac{e^{t (-z)}}{t^n}\,dt$$ is the  exponential integral function.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, as $x \to 0$ you have that the function tends to zero. You can conclude that it is then bounded near $0$, so the integral $\int _0 ^\epsilon$ is well-defined and bounded by comparison for some $\epsilon > 0$. By your observations of continuity (well, bounded is enough) we clearly have that $\int_{\epsilon} ^1$ exists.

Comment: @mariasca23 , so does that true for any real number $a$ ?